# PYTHON 3.6 replacing the elements of a matrix by the elements of a vector SNAIL/SPIRAL MATRIX AGAIN

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I hope you'r doing awesome.

I need your help, im trying to do some matrices like this

```
[2  3]
[7  5]

[17  19  23]
[13  2   3 ]
[11  7   5 ]

[17  19  23  29]
[13  2   3   31]
[11  7   5   37]
[53  47  43  41]
```

As you can see, these matrices are made of prime numbers organiced in a snail/spiral form.
I'm almost there. Let me explain to you what I've done.

first, I made an "base matrix", just like this for a 4x4 example

```
[6  7  8   9]
[5  0  1  10]
[4  3  2  11]
[15 14 13 12]
```

Second, I made a vector made of the first 16 prime numbers without the 1, for this example. Just like this

```
 [  2.   3.   5.   7.  11.  13.  17.  19.  23.  29.  31.  37.  41.  43.  47. 53.]
```

And Third, i want to replace the elements of the vector in the matrix, but this final step is my problem

I have tried with this code

```
n = input("enter the length of the matrix (maximum 12): ")

if (n <= 0):
   print("please enter a positive integer")

elif (n > 0):
   M = np.zeros([n, n])
   init = 0
   nlimit = n - 1
   c = 0                                       

   if (n % 2 == 0):
       while (c < (n*n)):
           for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
               c = c + 1
               M[nlimit, i] = c
           for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
               c = c + 1
               M[i, nlimit] = c
           for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
               c = c + 1
               M[init, i] = c
           for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
               c = c + 1
               M[i, init] = c
           init = init + 1
           nlimit = nlimit - 1


   if (n % 2 != 0):
       while (c < ((n*n)-1)):
           for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
               c = c + 1
               M[init, i] = c
           for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
               c = c + 1
               M[i, init] = c
           for i in range(init, nlimit, 1):
               c = c + 1
               M[nlimit, i] = c
           for i in range(nlimit, init, -1):
               c = c + 1
               M[i,nlimit] = c 
           init = init +1
           nlimit = nlimit - 1
       M[(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2] = n * n


R = (n*n)*np.ones([n,n])  
T = R - M             #T = base matrix
A = T
print(T)


q = 1                                             
w=np.zeros(n*n)
w[0] = 2

for i in range(3,1000,2):
    p = 0 
    for j in range (3,i+1,2):

        if (i % j == 0):
            p = p + 1

    if (p == 1):
        w[q] = i
        q = q + 1   

    if (q == (n*n)):
        break

print (w)


for k in range (0,n*n,1):
    for m in range (0, n-1, 1):
        for z in range (0, n-1, 1):
            if (T[m,z] == k): 
                A[m,z] = w[k]
print(A)
```

I know that my mistake is in the las 6 lines, but i don't know what it is.
This program will show you three thing
1) the base matrix
2) the prime number vector 
3) the spiral matrix with prime numbers

for n=4 this is the output

```
[[  6.   7.   8.   9.]
 [  5.   0.   1.  10.]
 [  4.   3.   2.  11.]
 [ 15.  14.  13.  12.]]

[  2.   3.   5.   7.  11.  13.  17.  19.  23.  29.  31.  37.  41.  43.  47. 53.]

[[ 17.  19.  23.   9.]
 [ 43.  43.  19.  10.]
 [ 37.  19.  43.  11.]
 [ 15.  14.  13.  12.]]
```

As you can see the last matrix isn't right.

I really really need your help, i hope you can do it, thank you so much.

Comment: do you plan on accepting any answer in any of your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you're almost there.

Just use your pre-generated matrix with prime number indices for accessing your vector of prime numbers (last few lines only):

```
for k in range(n):
    for m in range(n):
        idx = int(A[k,m])
        A[k,m] = w[idx]
print(A)
```

The element `A[k,m]` in you pre-generated matrix is the index of the prime number you want. You need to convert it to `int` (from `float`) in order to use it for indexing.

The result is as you expect:

```
[[ 17.  19.  23.  29.]
 [ 13.   2.   3.  31.]
 [ 11.   7.   5.  37.]
 [ 53.  47.  43.  41.]]
```

Comment: You're welcome! Just please note the best way to thank someone for an answer on StackOverflow is to [upvote and/or accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).